# File Manager Blank Screen On Create New Folder or File

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-files, themes, icons

This happens most often than not. Whenever I create a new folder or file in the File Manager, the whole file manager goes blank. I mean all the existing listing disappears including the one that I just created. Right clicking again brings back everything along with the untitled folder I had just created. Is this a theme thing?

**Edit:** I use pop-lite theme and ePapirus icon theme.

As you can see here, I created a new file. But No file icon. Instead, an already existing folder by the name of reg changed to rename node

[image: Note Here I created a new file. But No file icon. Instead, an already existing folder by the name of reg changed to rename node]

Then after right clicking
[image: Then after right clicking]

Elementary OS 5.1.4 Hera.
Everything updated.

Comment: Does the view go blank before or after renaming?  When "New File" or "New Folder" is clicked you should get a new file item which is already in rename mode - the name cell is replaced by a text entry widget.  Try running FIles in interactive debug mode with `GTK_DEBUG=interactive io.elementary.files.  Then you can temporarily change the theming to see whether that makes a difference.

Comment: It goes to blank as soon as I click new file or folder option from the right click menu. Whether or not its in the rename mode is impossible to see as everything disappears in thet view. The titlebar and sidepane are all there but the inside view goes white. If I right click again it appears and the folder is now simply names untitled folder.

Comment: Interesting. Can you can re-name an existing file or folder without difficulty?  Have you tried changing the theme temporarily?

Comment: I tried installing the arc-theme from the Ubuntu Bionic repo and did not have any problem creating and renaming a new file/folder.  Can you check which icon theme you are using (although it is not obvious how that would cause the problem).  Where did you get the themes from?  Is there anything else you have customised?

Comment: I have edited my question. I will now try and see if I can reproduce this error on different icon and GTK themes.

Comment: Very strange.  Do you get the same effect if you create a new folder using `<Ctrl><Shift>N` shortcut rather than using the background context menu?

Comment: Ok I changed the GTK theme to Arc and Icon theme to Papirus. Now the issue seem to have gone away. I guess this was a ePapirus icon theme, Pop GTK theme issue. I will still watch this for a couple of days.

Comment: I can understand how an incompatible icon theme could result in no icons.  I am surprised the text renderer was also affected.  I am glad you found a solution anyway.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem arising from incomplete icon theme ePapirus. I would advise against using it as of May 2020.